# Change JFrame display when JTabbedPane tab is selected

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, jtabbedpane

I am trying to make a JFrame display a different JPanel when a specific tab is selected.  I have tried adding code to make it add the new panel based on which tab index is selected.

Where am I going wrong with this?  What do I need to add to make it work?  Thanks.

EDIT

Here is my solved SSCCE:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainPanel {

    private static JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    private static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(MainPanel::createAndShowGUI);
    }

    protected static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        DrawGraphics drawGraphics = new DrawGraphics();
        DrawDifferentGraphics drawDifferentGraphics = new DrawDifferentGraphics();
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.WEST);

        tabbedPane.addTab("CFG", null);
        tabbedPane.addTab("CNX", null);

        frame.add(drawGraphics);

        tabbedPane.addChangeListener(e -> {

            if (tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex() == 0) {

                frame.remove(drawDifferentGraphics);
                frame.add(drawGraphics);
                frame.validate();
                frame.repaint();

            }

            if (tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex() == 1) {

                frame.remove(drawGraphics);
                frame.add(drawDifferentGraphics);
                frame.validate();
                frame.repaint();

            }});


        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class DrawGraphics extends JPanel {

    private ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();

    public DrawGraphics() {

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        shapes.add(new Ellipse2D.Double(10, 10, 20, 20));
        shapes.add(new Ellipse2D.Double(10, 30, 20, 20));
        shapes.add(new Ellipse2D.Double(10, 50, 20, 20));
        shapes.add(new Ellipse2D.Double(10, 70, 20, 20));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        shapes.forEach(g2d::fill);

        g2d.dispose();
    }
}

class DrawDifferentGraphics extends JPanel {

    private ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();

    public DrawDifferentGraphics() {

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        shapes.add(new Rectangle2D.Double(10, 10, 10, 10));
        shapes.add(new Rectangle2D.Double(10, 30, 10, 10));
        shapes.add(new Rectangle2D.Double(10, 50, 10, 10));
        shapes.add(new Rectangle2D.Double(10, 70, 10, 10));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);

        shapes.forEach(g2d::fill);

        g2d.dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to display the graphics on the panel next to the tabbedPane.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a ChangeListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/changelistener.html).

You will be notified when a tab has been clicked. You then get the selected tab and add the panel to the frame.

So basically your `if (tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex() == 0)` logic would be moved to the ChangeListener.

Or instead of having a bunch of "if statement" you could have a Map of Integer/JPanel values. Then you just get the index and get the panel from the Map.

Once you add the panel to the frame you then need to revalidate() and repaint() the frame.

Edit:

Actually the above suggestion is not complete. You can't just keep adding panels to the frame. The CENTER area of the BorderLayout should only contain a single component, otherwise you can get painting problems.

This can be demonstrated by clicking on the unselected tab, and then resize the frame. The original panel will be displayed.

You need to do one of the following:

1. Use a `CardLayout` (read the tutorial if you haven't used layout before) on a penel in the CENTER of the BordreLayout. So in this case the panel using the CardLayout is the only component in the CENTER and then it manages the panel that is displayed in the CardLayout. So your `ChangeListener` would need to identify the card to be displayed. You could set the card identifier to be the text of the selected tab. So
2. Remove the current panel BEFORE adding the new panel. In this case there is only a single panel in the CENTER so painting is as expected.

Comment: Thanks.  I will try this out.

Comment: @feltersnach, actually I'm not sure how the code works. You missed my point about the revalidate() and repaint(). See my edit about a problem with your code.

Comment: Why are you using invalidate() and validate()? I repeated my suggestion twice. Where did I make that suggestion? Also the code may work for two panels. Also, anytime you use "if else" logic it does not scale if you need 10 panels. Always try to use generic solutions. A generic solution is less error prone.